# Can this type of association be built via has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many-through

I want `a.items` to return all `Items` from all `Projects`.
But it returns nothing... 
I can gain items with `a.projects.first.items`, `a.projects.second.items` queries and so on, but I don't like this approach to list individual projects...

Is it possible to create such association with has_many :though (or other keywords) to return all items from all projects?

```
a = Account.first
a.items <---- return nothing via has_many :through
```

Here's generated SQL for `a.items`

> SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "items"."id" =
>   "projects"."item_id" WHERE "projects"."account_id" = ? 
>   [["account_id", 1]]

Judging from SQL statement I think the problem occurs because `Project` model has `item_id` field. But this is because a `Project` is a special type of an `Item`.

**account.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: accounts
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :projects
    has_many :items, :through => :projects
end
```

**project.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  account_id :integer
#  item_id    :integer
#

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    belongs_to :item
    has_many :items    
end
```

**item.rb**

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: items
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  name             :string
#  project_id       :integer
#

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project    
end
```

Comment: Is it correct to say a Project `belongs_to` an Item? I would try removing this incase it is confusing Rails.

Comment: Removing helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Brian Tompsett. His recommendation was correct.
After I removed cyclic belongs_to dependency Item <--> Project code starts to work as I wanted.

Here's working code:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    # belongs_to :item <---- Comment this line
    has_many :items    
end
```